# ZendServer CE - change database type?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-server

I am using the trial version of the Zend Server edition. From all the videos/documentation supposedly you are able to change the database version from SQLITE to MySQL, but all I get when deploying an application on Zend Server is to set the Host, Database name, username and password?

Comment: There is no trial of zend server ce. CE = community edition = free for ever. You have a trial of Zend Server the commercial product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just install mysql on your system and use it. ZendServer does not care what database engine you use. When installing Zend Server it is supposed to ask if you want to install mysql (possibly you have to chose manual installation or custom or extra stuff) you might of mised that option so perhapds reinstalling is the simpler solution.

But really, you should be able to just install mysql and start using it.